# Understanding htop

Tags: ram, htop

I am trying to make sense out of htop. I have a virtual PC with 6 GB RAM running ubuntu 15.10. I have installed a few applications on the server: Jenkins, Artifactory and some other tools. When I run htop I get this:

[image]

When I look at the **VIRT** and **RES** column the numbers far exceed the overview in the top showing that 1615/5967 MB is currently consumed.

How do I get a *real* view of how much RAM the the different applications on the server consumes?

By default **Hide kernel threads** are selected:

[image]

I have tried to enable **Hide userland threads** and the list now makes more sense:

[image]

Duplicates are still shown but at least only the "expected" memory consumption are shown for one instance of the applications. Not sure if its recommended to have this setting enabled though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does VIRT, RES and SHR means in the top command?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176001/what-does-virt-res-and-shr-means-in-the-top-command)

Comment: Its only covers part of my question. I would also like to know if its possible to get see what each application uses instead of the above list of endless duplicate instances of the same application even though only one instance is in fact running for each.

Comment: "…endless duplicate instances of the same application even though only one instance is in fact running for each" ... What does that mean? If you have several instances of the same application running, you'll see one entry for each instance.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot above at least two instances of Jenkins is "supposed" to be running and at least 10+ instances of artifactory. If that was really the case all memory on the machine would have been consumed, instead it shows that only 1615/5967 is consumed.

Comment: If those are threads of the same JVM, the memory would be shared.  See http://askubuntu.com/q/754816/158442, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe htop defaults on how many threads the main process is using and will show all of them. You can edit this out in the htop config file. goto: ~/.config/htop/htoprc. or try in htop press F2 and goto display options and press space select "hide kernel threads" and "hid userland threads" Should trim it down for you.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, VIRT colmn is how much memory the process can use for that process. E.g. artifacto mapped it self 4612M to use.

RES- This represents how much memory it is currently using. For Artifacto is is currently using 722M.

Here is a link with some more info subject;
[HTOP reference](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/what-is-difference-among-virt-res-and.html)

Comment: Ok so I should simply ignore the multiple entries for both artifactory and jenkins and just select one to understand how much the application is consuming?

Comment: I believe htop defaults on how many threads the main process is using and  will show all of them. You can edit this out in the htop config file. goto: ~/.config/htop/htoprc.  or try in htop press F2 and goto display options and press space select "hide kernel threads" and "hid userland threads" Should trim it down for you.

Comment: @esefram your comment above is the answer I was looking for could you add that as an answer?

Comment: yeah sure thing